# How to return SeekBar value to previous activity?

Tags: java, android, seekbar, startactivityforresult

How to return  `seekBar` value from **Activity B** to **Activity A** ?

```
seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarPercentage);

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  //return to previous activity {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
        Project=project.getSelectedItem().toString(); //spinner value
        Description=description.getText().toString(); //editText value
        // seekBar value ?
        returnIntent.putExtra("Project",Project);
        returnIntent.putExtra("Description",Description);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    }
});

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    int progress = 0;

    @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progresValue;
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changing seekbar's progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            progressText.setText("Covered: " + progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped tracking seekbar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem? You nearly got everything you need? You can get the progress via `getProgress()`

Comment: @oberflansch sorry, new here. There are nothing wrong with my code, I just don't know how to get the `seekBar` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Keep the `int progress` outside the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`.
2. Retrieve current progress as `progress = seekBar.getProgress()`.
3. Similar to `returnIntent.putExtra("Description",Description);`, put the `progress` in the `Intent` as an extra.

Comment: Ok, so set the `int progress` as global and `returnIntent.putExtra("progress",progress);` ? Do I need to get something ?

Comment: Use `getProgress()` to get the current value of the `SeekBar`.

Comment: Edited my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @Anindya Dutta's Answer if you want to persist the data use `SharedPreferences`

**Get `SharedPreferences`**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

**Read preferences:**

```
String key = "test1_string_pref";
String default = "returned_if_not_defined";
String test1 = prefs.getString(key, default);
```

**To edit and save preferences**

```
SharedPreferences.Edtior editor = prefs.edit(); //Get SharedPref Editor
editor.putString(key, "My String");
editor.commit();
```

**Shorter way to write**

```
prefs.edit().putString(key, "Value").commit();
```

Additional info for SharedPreferences: [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [Android Developers Article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)